# OpenLayers.Format.SLD - Ignores 'matchCase'?

Tags: openlayers-2, sld, filter, format

I've trying to use OpenLayers to construct an SLD element to include in a WMS layer's parameters.

This SLD document can contain a number of filters. This works fine and resultant SLD does work to filter the layer.

However, the `matchCase=false` property of the filter(s) are being stripped out on formatting the SLD.

Example:

```
var filter    = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison(
{
  type:       OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
  property:   'my_property',
  value:      'A Value',
  matchCase:  false
});

var rule = new OpenLayers.Rule({
  filter: filter,
  symbolizer: {"Polygon": {}}
});

var style = new OpenLayers.Style();

style.addRules([rule]);

// Create the SLD
var sld_body = new OpenLayers.Format.SLD().write({
  namedLayers: [
    {
      name: 'myLayer',
      userStyles: [style]
    }
  ]
});
```

I think I know what the problem is, but I have no idea how to fix it.

If I check the output of `OpenLayers.Format.Filter({version: "1.1.0"}).write( filter );` then I see correctly formatted XML, which includes my `matchedCase` property.

If I do the same with version 1.0 (the default), I see the same XML but **without** the `matchedCase` parameter.

The documentation for `OpenLayers.Format.SLD` states that it inherits from `OpenLayers.Format.Filter.v1_0_0`, which explains why it won't read the `matchedCase` parameter.

I'd hoped using `OpenLayers.Format.SLD({version: "1.1.0}).write()` would work, but it just throws an error about a driver not being available for that version.

So, how should I deal with this? I need to generate an SLD document and it needs to acknowledge the matchedCase property.

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Officially, OpenLayers only supports SLD version 1.0.0 for now (patch welcome). I'm not sure this version of the SLD standard officially supports Filters version 1.1.0. That's the official standard point of view.

In the real world however, your WMS service probably do support it. So to force OpenLayers SLD version 1.0.0 to use Filters version 1.1.0, you can overwrite them like this:

```
var filter    = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison(
{
  type:       OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
  property:   'my_property',
  value:      'A Value',
  matchCase:  false
});

var rule = new OpenLayers.Rule({
  filter: filter,
  symbolizer: {"Polygon": {}}
});

var style = new OpenLayers.Style();

style.addRules([rule]);

// Create the SLD
OpenLayers.Format.SLD.v1.prototype.readers = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults(
    OpenLayers.Format.Filter.v1_1_0.prototype.readers, 
    OpenLayers.Format.SLD.v1.prototype.readers);
OpenLayers.Format.SLD.v1.prototype.writers = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults(
    OpenLayers.Format.Filter.v1_1_0.prototype.writers, 
    OpenLayers.Format.SLD.v1.prototype.writers);
OpenLayers.Format.SLD.v1.prototype.writeSpatial = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults(
    OpenLayers.Format.Filter.v1_1_0.prototype.writeSpatial, 
    OpenLayers.Format.SLD.v1.prototype.writeSpatial);
var sld_body = new OpenLayers.Format.SLD().write({
  namedLayers: [
    {
      name: 'myLayer',
      userStyles: [style]
    }
  ]
});
```

The code highlighted below replace all the Filter1.0.0 writing functions by Filter1.1.0 in the SLD class.

```
OpenLayers.Format.SLD.v1.prototype.writers = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults(
    OpenLayers.Format.Filter.v1_1_0.prototype.writers, 
    OpenLayers.Format.SLD.v1.prototype.writers);
```

Comment: Worked a treat. I'd upvote but not enough rep... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I did not have any luck with the accepted answer (although I am working with a GeoJSON layer, not WMS, so perhaps that makes the difference), but I found a sloppy workaround via some find-and-replace magic in the 1.1.0 SLD file:

1. Changed beginning of file (xml prologue is it called??) to match 1.0 standards:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <sld:StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
   xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
   xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
   xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">`
2. Changed all instances of `SvgParameter` to `CssParameter` (credit to the suggestion at the end of [this post](http://cartaro.org/blog/14-how-use-qgis-great-looking-symbols-cartaro)).
3. Changed all instances of `<se:whatever>stuff</se:whatever>` to `<sld:whatever>stuff</sld:whatever>` (this may have been just a QGIS feature, I am not sure).

Like I said, not pretty, but it allowed me to adapt a 1.1.0 SLD file exported from QGIS, which I was then able to use in OpenLayers.